# Unwanted % sign at the end of java program

Tags: java, linux, symbols

Every program that I write and run (all of these have been CLI) runs fine, but then ends the program with a % sign.

This does nothing to the running of the program, but is looks odd to the markers when they see it (marking off my computer).

This happens on both of my computers, both of which run a similar form of Arch Linux, and both of which are running the same code from a Guake terminal editor.

Comment: What are you talking about? The sourcecode contains `%` or the program outputs additional `%` characters at runtime?

Comment: ..and your question is?  BTW - don't include sigs. in questions, if your name is that important to you, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2339299/user2339299).

Comment: This is obviously your shell/prompt, and has nothing to do with java.

Comment: It could be an escape sequence at your prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using zsh, which, as a feature, always prepends a new line to a new prompt. However, it tells you about that using said % sign. Add a "\n" to every last line of your program output and you should stop seeing the sign.